# How to Display data from moodle database in an html table

Tags: php, html-table, moodle

How to Display data from **moodle database** in **html table**.

**What I tried..**

```
$all_response = get_response_details($refid);
    if($all_response){
    $all_response = array_values($all_response);
    $responseCount = count($all_response);
    //table
    $table = new html_table();
    $table->head = array('Name ','email', 'status', 'Grade');   
    for($k=0;$k<$responseCount;$k++)
    {
        $stud_details = get_student_detail($all_response[$k]->student_id);//student details
        $stud_details = array_values($stud_details);
        $quest_details = get_quetion_by_id($all_response[$k]->qn_id, $all_response[$k]->ref_id);

        $table->data = array(array($stud_details[0]->firstname, $stud_details[0]->email,  $all_response[$k]->sub_status, $grade_date));

     echo html_writer::table($table);   
    }
```

But the problem is separate tables are displayed for each data. That is if 3 records are there then shows three tables.

I put `echo html_writer::table($table);` outside the for loop then only one row should be displayed.

I have to display all records in single table. Any help is appreciated....

I am using **Moodle 2.7**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try

```
    // Add the [] to data and just a single array.
    $table->data[] = array($stud_details[0]->firstname, $stud_details[0]->email,  $all_response[$k]->sub_status, $grade_date);

 }
 // Outside the loop.
 echo html_writer::table($table);
```